# Firebase Crashlytics ObjectOutputStream writeObject0 Error

Tags: java, android, crashlytics

I'm trying to solve the crash problems of our project lately. I've seen this crash but couldn't find any reason for it. We don't have anything related to "output stream" also Crashlytics doesn't show the exact problem. How can I find the cause?

```
Caused by java.io.NotSerializableException
e.j.a.a.j.f.g.a
  java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0 (ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
  java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields (ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
```

also

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = e.j.a.a.j.f.g.b)
  android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable (Parcel.java:1836)
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: It seems like you don't know Android Obfuscation to find out read from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code). also, The solution of your problem might be here [Get deobfuscated crash reports with the Firebase Crashlytics SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=android) and [Deobfuscate or symbolicate crash stack traces](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en#zippy=)

Comment: @MuhammadFarhan I've couldn't get back to you and honestly wasn't expect an answer that fast. I'll check what you mentioned. Thank you